Build wasm with import memory wasm
I want to write code in rust which I will then compile into wasm so that it uses import memory.
In the compiled file the wasm from rust want to see similar code
(module
  (import "host" "mem" (memory 1))
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello")
  ...

How to do it?
I found this:
#![feature(wasm_import_memory)]
#![wasm_import_memory]

and this:
rustflags = [
  "-C", "link-args=--import-memory",
]

but adding any of them doesn't add import memory
Full example:
Code rust:
#![feature(wasm_import_memory)]
#![wasm_import_memory]

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn add(data: *mut i32) {
    unsafe {*data += 1;}
}

Сompiled from this wasm code:
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i32)))
  (func (;0;) (type 0) (param i32)
    local.get 0
    local.get 0
    i32.load
    i32.const 1
    i32.add
    i32.store)
  (table (;0;) 1 1 funcref)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;2;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "add" (func 0))
  (export "__data_end" (global 1))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 2)))

but i want:
(module
  (import "host" "mem" (memory 1))
  (data (i32.const 0) "Hello")

  (type (;0;) (func (param i32)))
  (func (;0;) (type 0) (param i32)
    local.get 0
    local.get 0
    i32.load
    i32.const 1
    i32.add
    i32.store)
  (table (;0;) 1 1 funcref)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;2;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "add" (func 0))
  (export "__data_end" (global 1))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 2)))


Rust does not yet support multiple memories, even LLVM seem to not support them (although it has the potential to support them via its addrspace attribute, but it's not clear this is the best way to do that, as per this thread).
It is not easy to support: in order to do that, one of the following will have to happen:

Every pointer becomes a fat pointer, carrying the memory in addition to the address. This is very unlikely to happen as it's prohibitively expensive. Also consider that the memory index must be an immediate in load/store, and it that isn't changed, it will require every load/store to branch on the memory index.
The language is changed somehow to support that. This will likely include some way of annotating pointers and static with an associated memory. This is the most likely path forward, but beyond changed to LLVM to support that, it will require an quite big design work in order to get that properly.

This doesn't mean it is completely impossible to somewhat support multiple memories without language support. Postprocessing the generated wasm file can do some things (wasm-bindgen does it). For example, you can require every load/store from a memory that isn't the default memory to happen through a #[inline(never)] #[no_mangle] function, and then look for that in the wasm file and replace it with instructions to load/store to other memories. This can be further improved by providing a wrapper type that wraps an address and provides convenient functions to do that. But in addition to this being fragile (depending on the optimizer to do the correct thing), it also will never be as comfortable as proper language support. You cannot provide references to other memories, and without references not a lot can be done. The best you can do is copy memory, do some work, then copy it back (and even that has to be very careful when exposing a safe interface to not accidentally become unsound).
